# Dynamic class type from file data

Tags: c++, json, class, templates, reflection

I have some JSON files in which I define objects of various types.  The types are given as a field within the objects.  I want to load the file and for each JSON object, create a new class of that type and pass the rest of the JSON data to its constructor.

The issue is that I'd rather not have a huge case statement matching the type and creating an object of that type.  Here are some of the possibilities I've considered:

1. Reflection.  I don't know too much about it, but my understanding is that it might allow me to create a class in this manner.  While I'm aware C++ doesn't provide this capability natively, I've seen a few libraries [such as this one](https://github.com/rttrorg/rttr) that might provide such functionality.
2. Create an enum of class types.  Create a template function that takes a type parameter from this enum and creates an object of that type.  Use something like smart_enum to convert the string field.

Option 2 seems like a good one but I haven't been able to get this working.  I've done extensive googling, but no luck.  Does anyone know how I might go about doing this, or if there is a better option which I have not considered?  Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, perhaps under a term which I do not know; I have spent quite a lot of time trying to solve this problem and had no luck.

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information, and thank you.

Edit: here's an example of what I've tried to get option 2 working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class Animals {
    Dog,
    Cat
};

class Dog {
public:
    std::string sound{"woof"};
};

class Cat {
public:
    std::string sound{"meow"};
};

template<Animals animal> void make_sound() {
    new animal();
    cout << animal.sound << endl;
}

int main() {
    make_sound<Animals::Dog>();
    make_sound<Animals::Cat>();

    std::exit(1);
}
```

Comment: There's no reflection available in c++, so you're left to option 2 only.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you, I've seen a few libraries that offer it, but that's what I thought.  How would I implement option 2?  I've been unable to get it working.  I'm editing with an example of my non-working code in the main question.

Comment: Here are some hints for starters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007382/how-to-create-class-objects-dynamically It's a quite broad topic, _too broad_ to be answered here concisely.

Comment: Thanks, the factory idea looks like a potential solution.  Is there a way to do what I was trying for in my code above, make an enum of potential classes and generate a template function for each, then convert strings to enum members?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is there potentially a way to implement the factory idea in the question you linked with templates, enumerating the list of possible types and creating a factory for each?

Comment: A template might help in some specific cases, but what you're basically looking for is _de-/serialization_. If you look that up, you'll find plethora of examples: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&sxsrf=ALeKk02q17n27r6MSiDT8-k9fUphIlgnpg%3A1603757396955&ei=VGWXX9rkOY_asAff0LnYBA&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+serialize+objects+file&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+serialize+objects+file&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1D3rwFYnrkBYKLKAWgAcAJ4AIABqwGIAbkDkgEDMC4zmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwja3s3vvdPsAhUPLewKHV9oDksQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: Respectively for JSON: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&sxsrf=ALeKk02jbzlxM0cWBK5lx9MfbKvnv-6Svg%3A1603757423843&ei=b2WXX7_3MpGbkwX1u4DgBQ&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+serialize+objects+file+json&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+serialize+objects+file+json&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1CcxAJYw84CYMjYAmgAcAJ4AIABVogBowOSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj_6rb8vdPsAhWRzaQKHfUdAFwQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, #1 is out, C++ lacks reflection (until [P0194](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0194r6.html) gets adopted).

#2 still requires a big ol' switch block because you're still have to switch on a run-time type ID.

So, I'll propose #3: use a template to generate all those case statements you don't want to have to write (well, a map anyway).

This is the final code, which uses [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library for JSON parsing since that's the one that's available from godbolt :).

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct option {
    using type = T;
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>, "constructor doesn't exist");

    static T create(const nlohmann::json& json) {
        return create_impl(json, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    }

    template <size_t... Is>
    static T create_impl(const nlohmann::json& json, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return { json[Is].get<Args>()... };
    }
};

template <typename...>
struct to_string {
    using type = std::string_view;
};

template <typename... Options>
struct factory_builder {
    using variant = std::variant<typename Options::type...>;

    factory_builder(typename to_string<Options>::type... names) 
        : map { std::pair<std::string, std::function<variant(const nlohmann::json&)>> { names, [](const nlohmann::json& json) -> variant { return Options::create(json); } }... }
    { }

    variant operator ()(const nlohmann::json& json) {
        return map[json["type"].get<std::string>()](json["args"]);
    }
    
    std::map<std::string, std::function<variant(const nlohmann::json&)>> map;
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
using factory_t = factory_builder<
    option<Dog, double, std::string>, // Dog & its constructor argument types
    option<Cat, int>                  // Cat & its constructor argument types
>;
factory_t factory("Dog", "Cat");      // String type identifiers for each option
auto my_object = factory( /* ... your JSON */ );
```

It assumes the JSON takes this form, where "type" is one of the string identifiers passed to the `factory_builder` constructor, and "args" is a list of arguments:

```json
{ 
    "type": "TheTypeIdentifier",
    "args": [42, "whatever", false]
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/3qfP9G

---

That's a lot of code, so let's break it down. First problem you need to solve is how to actually have a variable that can be more than one type, since C++ is strongly typed. C++17 provides [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) for this, so we'll use that.

```cpp
using result = std::variant<Dog, Cat>;
result example_result = Dog {};
example_result = Cat {};
```

Next, you need a way to generically describe, at compile time, how to construct an object: I used a simple struct with a template argument for the type, and a variable number of template arguments for the types going into that constructor:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct options;
```

Given a `option<T, Args...>`, how do you take a JSON array and pass those items to the constructor? With the nlohmann library, if you have a parsed JSON array called `my_array` and want to get index `n` and store it in an object of type `T`:

```cpp
my_array[n].get<T>(); // accesses the array, converts, and returns a T&
```

To do that generically, I took the parameter pack of arguments and converted it into a parameter pack of increasing integers (0, 1, 2...) using [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). Then I expanded the two parameter packs into `T` and `n` in the example above. It was convenient to put all this inside a static method of `option<T, Args...>`:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct option {
    /* ... */

    static T create(const nlohmann::json& json) {
        return create_impl(json, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    }

    template <size_t... Is>
    static T create_impl(const nlohmann::json& json, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return { json[Is].get<Args>()... };
    }
};
```

That solves extracting arguments and calling a constructor for *one* type generically. Next problem is, how do you generate a function that switches on the type name and calls one of those `Option<T, ...>::create` functions?

For this solution, I used a map from strings to an `std::function` that takes JSON in and outputs our variant type:

```cpp
template <typename... Options>
struct factory_builder {
    // note: using a typedef "type" in options<T, Args...> that just points to T
    using variant = std::variant<typename Options::type...>;

    factory_builder(/* one string for each type */) 
    {
        // TODO: populate map
    }

    variant operator ()(const nlohmann::json& json) {
        return map[json["type"].get<std::string>()](json["args"]);
    }
    
    std::map<std::string, std::function<variant(const nlohmann::json&)>> map;
};
```

Now we just need to build that map. First, a detour: how do you ask for one string per type in a parameter pack? I used a helper type that takes a template argument and has a typedef that is always a string. Expand into that, and you get a parameter pack of string types:

```
template <typename...>
struct to_string {
    using type = std::string_view;
};
```

Then, to populate the map, you can do that right from the initializer list:

```cpp
using map_t = std::map<std::string, std::function<variant(const nlohmann::json&)>>;
factory_builder(...) : map {
    typename map_t::value_type {
        names, 
        [](const nlohmann::json& json) -> variant {
            return Options::create(json);
        }
    }... 
}
```

This is a little confusing, but it's expanding into something like this:

```cpp
factory_builder(std::string dogName, std::string catName) : map {
    std::pair<...> { dogName, [](auto& j) { return Dog(...); } },
    std::pair<...> { catName, [](auto& j) { return Cat(...); } }
}
```

And that's it! Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you.  Much appreciated, especially the great explanation!

Comment: Quick follow-up question: how would you make this return an unique_ptr?

Comment: The issue seems to be that I have to get the object like this: `std::get<Dog>(obj).makesound()`.  Is there any way I can get a clean pointer from this with the correct type attached, like `std::unique_ptr<Dog>`?

Comment: The proper way is to use methods of a variant is to call std::visit: `std::visit([](auto&& animal) { a.makesound(); }, obj);`. If you want to deal with pointers, you can use an abstract base type with virtual methods. Is that something you have the flexibility to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of C++ JSON libraries that support mapping polymorphic or `std::variant` types based on some type selection strategy, which could rely on a type marker (e.g. "cat", "dog"), or alternatively the presence or absence of members. Lacking reflection, such libraries rely on traits. Typically the library provides built-in traits specializations for standard library types such as `std::chrono::duration` and `std::vector`, and supports custom specializations for user types. Some libraries offer convenience macros that can be used to generate the code for custom specializations.

The library [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer) has an example of encoding/decoding JSON for [polymorphic types](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example3.md).

The library [jsoncons](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons) has examples of encoding/decoding JSON for [polymorphic types](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons/blob/master/doc/Examples.md#G14) and the [std::variant type](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons/blob/master/doc/Examples.md#G15)